# How to use Azure DevOps for building React Applications?

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, snowpack

Can we use Build Tools like "WebPack" or "SnowPack" within Azure DevOps for building React Applications?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, yes, I use Azure DevOps to create pipelines and releases for react apps all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the build pipeline for your React App, we have provided the template (**`Node.js with React`**) for use.

In this template, it has contained the basic tasks to build the React App. You can add other tasks or delete the existing tasks as needed.

[image]

For more details, you also can reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code#react-and-vue).